# Create a new file with Names and path to the files in linux

Tags: text-processing, files

I have several `fastq.gz` files, both R1 and R2 in a directory `dir` on a Linux system. It looks like:

```
dir
 |____sampleA_1.fastq.gz
 |____sampleA_2.fastq.gz
 |____sampleB_1.fastq.gz
 |____sampleB_2.fastq.gz
 |____sampleC_1.fastq.gz
 |____sampleC_2.fastq.gz
```

I wanted to create a `txt` file with sample name as first column, path to R1 fastq as second column and path to R2 fastq as third column.

Inside `dir` I tried in the following way:

```
find "$PWD" -name \*1.fastq.gz > list1.txt
find "$PWD" -name \*2.fastq.gz > list2.txt
```

And again I have to merge those two files and give a column name and again create another column with sample names. Instead, Is there a way to make the file with a single command?

And `txt` file should look like below:

```
sample            Second                    Third
sampleA    dir/sampleA_1.fastq.gz     dir/sampleA_2.fastq.gz
sampleB    dir/sampleB_1.fastq.gz     dir/sampleB_2.fastq.gz
sampleC    dir/sampleC_1.fastq.gz     dir/sampleC_2.fastq.gz
```

Comment: Is that really the format your files are in? Aren't they something like `sampleA_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz` and `sampleA_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz`? Do you really only have _one_ underscore (`_`) per file name? Also, can you be sure you will never have more than a single pair of reads per sample? Depending on coverage and size of the assay's target regions, you can have several.

Comment: Assuming there’s a common key between items (sample name?), a clever `join` might be able to do it

Comment: You might garner more interest in your question if you add keywords in your first paragraph (something like "Paired-End Sequencing"), and add a reference link. This helps orient potential answerers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks needlessly complicated, but it's handling the case where only one of the sample's files are present

```bash
{
    printf '%s\n' sample Second Third

    find ./dir/ -type f -name '*.fastq.gz' -print \
    | cut -d _ -f 1 \
    | sort -u \
    | bash -c '
        while read -r root; do
            echo "${root##*/}"
            for i in 1 2; do
                f="${root}_${i}.fastq.gz"
                [[ -f "$f" ]] && echo "$f" || echo ""
            done
        done
      ' 
} \
| paste - - - \
| column -s $'\t' -t
```

Testing:

```bash
mkdir dir
touch dir/sample{A,B,C}_{1,2}.fastq.gz
touch dir/sample{D_1,E_2}.fastq.gz
touch dir/ignore.me
```

Then the above command outputs

```
sample   Second                    Third
sampleA  ./dir/sampleA_1.fastq.gz  ./dir/sampleA_2.fastq.gz
sampleB  ./dir/sampleB_1.fastq.gz  ./dir/sampleB_2.fastq.gz
sampleC  ./dir/sampleC_1.fastq.gz  ./dir/sampleC_2.fastq.gz
sampleD  ./dir/sampleD_1.fastq.gz  
sampleE                            ./dir/sampleE_2.fastq.gz
```

---

Maybe this GNU awk version is a bit tidier:

```bash
find ./dir -type f | gawk -F/ -v OFS='\t' '
    BEGIN { print "sample", "Second", "Third" }
    match($NF, /^(.*)_([12]).fastq.gz$/, m) {
        file[m[1]][m[2]] = $0
    }
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for (sample in file)
            print sample, file[sample][1], file[sample][2]
    }
' | column -s $'\t' -t
```

Produces same output as above.

Comment: sorry, does your code work if the file are `tq.gz` instead of `fastq.gz`?

Comment: I hardcode "fast.gz" so no. Your question does not require otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

If you can guarantee that there are always a pair of samples, this `bash`/`ksh` code will generate the output based on the presence of all the sample 1 files:

Example (set up demo environment):

```bash
mkdir -p /tmp/710303/dir
cd /tmp/710303
touch dir/sample{A,B,C}_{1,2}.fastq.gz       # Assumes a { }-aware shell
```

File generation (work on the demo environment)

```bash
printf "%s %s %s\n" 'sample' 'Second' 'Third'
for f1 in dir/sample*_1.fastq*               # Loop through all first samples
do
    fn="${f1##*/}"; fn="${fn%%_*}"           # Label
    f2="${f1/1/2}"                           # Filename for second sample
    printf "%s %s %s\n" "$fn" "$f1" "$f2"    # Output the values
done
```

Output

```
sample Second Third
sampleA dir/sampleA_1.fastq.gz dir/sampleA_2.fastq.gz
sampleB dir/sampleB_1.fastq.gz dir/sampleB_2.fastq.gz
sampleC dir/sampleC_1.fastq.gz dir/sampleC_2.fastq.gz
```

These are space-separated columns. If you want tab-separated then change the `printf` format lines to use `\t` (tab) instead of   (space).

Comment: it should give a path to the second and third columns. No need a path for the first column. And how do I give the names for those columns?

Comment: @stack_learner titles and path added

Comment: Thank you very much. In the above script instead of `dir` I added `"$PWD"`.

Comment: The original version of the script would have suited you better, and then you would have just needed to add `$PWD` to the output values

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS="[/_]"; OFS="\t"
    print "sample", "Second", "Third"
}
NR%2 { second = $0; next }
{ print $2, second, $0 }
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' dir/* | awk -f tst.awk
sample  Second  Third
sampleA dir/sampleA_1.fastq.gz  dir/sampleA_2.fastq.gz
sampleB dir/sampleB_1.fastq.gz  dir/sampleB_2.fastq.gz
sampleC dir/sampleC_1.fastq.gz  dir/sampleC_2.fastq.gz
```

Comment: @Morton instead of `dir/*` I tries giving `"$PWD"` but it didn't work. Is there a way for that?

Comment: `$PWD` contains the current **directory** name (`Present Working Directory`), you need to pass **file** names to the command. Sounds like you might want `./*` or `"$PWD"/*`.

Comment: Yes I knew this. I tried `"$PWD"/*` this, `Second` and `Third` columns are ok, but column `sample` doesn't show the right names, instead it is showing the first directory of the `Present Working Directory`

Comment: idk, the script I provided produces the output you asked for from the sample input you provided so if there's some other input it doesn't work for then you'd have to provide that in your question. Looks like you already accepted an answer to this question, though, so you should ask a new followup question.